# Tylor's ways, he checked. (Hemingway's To Have and Have Not)

Tags: meaning

This is from *To Have and Have Not* by Ernest Hemingway.

Can anyone help me with the following sentence: "I saw her a couple of days ago on Ed. Taylor's ways, he checked."

> There are two speedboats that could catch us, Harry was thinking. One, Ray’s, is running the mail from Matecumbe. Where is the other? **I saw her a couple of days ago on Ed. Taylor’s ways, he checked.** That was the one I thought of having Bee-lips hire. There’s two more, he remembered now. One the State Road Department has up along the keys. The other’s laid up in the Garrison Bight.

I don't understand this "Ed." and "Taylor's ways."

Comment: The title is *To Have and Have Not*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the [meanings](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/ways) of *ways* is

> 18.  ( plural ) the wooden or metal tracks down which a ship slides to be launched

Ships are referred to as *she* in English, especially by sailors and *Ed* is [a contraction](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/ed) of *Edward* or *Edgar*.

So, I understand that passage as meaning:

> I saw her (the boat) on Edward Taylor's ways

In other words, the character had seen this particular boat on the ways of Mr. Ed Taylor. This means that that particular boat will not be able to catch them.